# Migrating multiple databases with Laravel Artisan

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-migration, laravel-artisan

I have my command `migrate:s` which contains the following

```
public function handle()
{

    $sites = Sites::all();


    foreach($sites as $site)
    {
        $host       = $site->h;
        $database   = $site->d;
        $username   = $site->u;
        $password   = $site->p;

        $this->info('Trying to migrate ' . $database);

        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host',      $host);
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database',  $database);
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username',  $username);
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password',  $password);

        //Reconnect with new credentials
        DB::reconnect('mysql');

        //Call the migration on the new connection
        $this->call('migrate');

        $this->info('Migrations complete for database ' . $site->d);
    }
}
```

The first site always migrates fine, however after it keeps trying to create the migration table despite there already being one, one that is populated.

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists
```

The credentials are correct for the databases, I cannot figure out *why* it's trying to make the table after the first migration.

Comment: Can you look at/post the contents of your migrations table on each site? I'm wondering if it got out of sync so it thinks it hasn't run the migration to create the migrations table? Also, what version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: @Loren 5.1, the migrations table is full, I have dropped the database, from a clean install, it always works on the first. Just playing around now, it seems it isn't syncing the credentials for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the settings were being cached, hence the first connection working, so you need to purge the connection by using

```
DB::purge('connectionName');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, it may be that the ->call function somehow reinitializes part of Laravel, or at least that's my best guess. If you have each site as a database connection (ie mysql1, mysql2, mysql3, etc), you might try using the --database option for migrate to run the migration and see if that helps?

The migrate command has an option for picking the database connection:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php

Comment: Tried, still the same result as base table not found.